# django under virtualenv causing importerror

Tags: django, virtualenv

In ubuntu lucid ,I installed python2.7.5 and set up a virtualenv .In the terminal I typed workon envpy275 and using pip installed these sw from requirements file

```
python==2.7.5
Django==1.4.3
South==0.7.6
distribute==0.6.28
dj-database-url==0.2.1
django-registration==0.8
numpy==1.4.1
matplotlib==1.2.0
psycopg2==2.4.6
python-memcached==1.48
simplejson==3.0.7
wsgiref==0.1.2

$workon envpy275
(envpy27)me@ubuntu:~/dev/python/django/myapp$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This installed these softwares into `~/.virtualenv/envpy275/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

My system already has `Django1.4` at `/home/me/Django-1.4`.and my .bashrc file has

```
PYTHONPATH=/home/me/Django-1.4
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/me/dev/python/django/myapp
```

since my project settings file is in `/home/me/dev/python/django/myapp/mysite directory`
I set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE as below

```
 (envpy27)me@ubuntu:~/dev/python/django/myapp$ export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='mysite.setings'
```

Then,at the terminal ,I try to run the django server

```
(envpy27)me@ubuntu:~/dev/python/django/myapp$ python manage.py runserver
```

This produced the following warning and error

```
/home/me/.virtualenvs/envpy275/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz/__init__.py:35: UserWarning: 
Module django was already imported from 
    /home/me/Django-1.4/django/__init__.pyc, but /home/me/.virtualenvs/envpy275/lib/python2.7/site-packages 
is being added to sys.path
 from pkg_resources import resource_stream
  ...
  ...
 file "/home/me/Django-1.4/django/conf/__init__.py", line 95, in __init__
  raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
 ImportError: Could not import settings 'mysite.setings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named setings
```

Comment: is `mysite.setings` visible to your program? Try adding it to PYTHONPATH and see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a typo where you set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to mysite.setings - normally this would be `mysite.settings` pointing to a file `mysite/settings.py`